# Tree recursion bugs

Tags: c++, tree

After debugging literally since Sunday the same code, I've officially given up and think its time someone else takes a look. I have spent hours and hours and cant image whats wrong with my code. Its a bit long, but its easy to follow, and I would really appreciate any help-you're the only choice I got now.

What I'm trying to do is implement a few functions that collectively do this: Given a quad tree where each leaf represents 1 pixel of an image, prune the tree to remove or combine similar colors. Each tree has a `root` node with 4 children, and so on. Each node has `x,y,width,height, and element` where width and height represent the block of pixels that represents that area and x,y represent the lower left corner pixel of the node and element is a type pixel. Each non-leaf node stores the average color of all of its children. If the difference in color of a certain non-leaf node `myNode` with one of its children leaf nodes is greater than the parameter `tol(or tolerance)`, then you cant prune. If there are no such cases, then you prune, meaning you'd remove all of the children of `myNode`, and `myNode` would then just store the average value of all the nodes it just deleted (which should be just automatic when the average is calculated in the code initially).

So, here's my codeflow:

- First I calculate and store the
  average of each node into its element
  pixel field.
- Now an outside function calls pruneSize on some tree. pruneSize does not actually prune, but just returns the number of leaves that would be remaining in the tree if you were to prune.
- From there, the code is commented. Basically in the deeper and signal function, I tried to make it so that if orig cannot be pruned for some reason, then now you have to check origs children to see if they can be pruned, and so on.

The problem is that I am not getting the correct output when I run it. It's off bigtime. I'm hoping the error will be easy to spot for the experienced among you.

(Also, the quadtree class is implemented perfectly. Everything else has been tested and works fine, so its something with my average calculator or pruneSize.)

Comment: Please post the full class definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be wrong here (just skimmed over it and can't verify right now), but as far as I'm aware, to square in C++, you need to explicitly multiply a number with itself. Doing `A^2` will calculate `A XOR 2`.

Comment: Ya you can see right under that I commented the line that would square it. I had it set up like that initially, but it didnt make a difference either way.

Comment: I put it back to normal in my code, the numbers are different now, but still off big time. Any other errors you see?

Comment: It seems like you removed your code, makes it kind of hard to check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

In `calculateAvg`, I think you should you call `calculateAvg` on the children *before* calculating your "own" average. Otherwise, it looks to me like the values your reading are either stale or undefined..

Comment: Hmm..did that now, didnt make a difference at all. Can you explain your case?

Comment: @bitmoe ok - I guess I missed that (calling it for the children first does mean you don't have to recurse in `avgHelper`, though, but that's besides the point)..